# Openmp c++ sobel edge detection

Tags: c++, openmp, edge-detection

I have a problem with final picture, it is distorted and I don't know why. It is only when I turn on openmp option in Visual Studio. If its working for one thread there is no problem and the edges are clear. The code is right below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<omp.h>
#include<cmath>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int xGradient(Mat image, int x, int y)
{
return image.at<uchar>(y-1, x-1) +
            2*image.at<uchar>(y, x-1) +
             image.at<uchar>(y+1, x-1) -
              image.at<uchar>(y-1, x+1) -
               2*image.at<uchar>(y, x+1) -
                image.at<uchar>(y+1, x+1);
}
int yGradient(Mat image, int x, int y)
{
    return image.at<uchar>(y-1, x-1) +
            2*image.at<uchar>(y-1, x) +
             image.at<uchar>(y-1, x+1) -
              image.at<uchar>(y+1, x-1) -
               2*image.at<uchar>(y+1, x) -
                image.at<uchar>(y+1, x+1);
}
int main()

 {

  Mat src, grey, dst;
 double start, end;
     start = omp_get_wtime();
  int gx, gy, sum;
src= imread("E:/image.jpg");  
cvtColor(src,grey,CV_BGR2GRAY);
  dst = grey.clone();
  if( !grey.data )
  { return -1; }
 #pragma omp parallel for  
  for(int y = 0; y < grey.rows; y++)
        for(int x = 0; x < grey.cols; x++)
            dst.at<uchar>(y,x) = 0;  
 #pragma omp parallel for
   for(int y = 1; y < grey.rows - 1; y++){
        for(int x = 1; x < grey.cols - 1; x++){
            gx = xGradient(grey, x, y);
            gy = yGradient(grey, x, y);
            sum = abs(gx) + abs(gy);
            sum = sum > 255 ? 255:sum;
            sum = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
            dst.at<uchar>(y,x) = sum;

                }
    }
    namedWindow("sobel");
    imshow("sobel", dst);
    namedWindow("grayscale");
    imshow("grayscale", grey);
    namedWindow("Original");
    imshow("Original", src);
    end = omp_get_wtime();
    cout<<"time is: "<<(end-start)<< " seconds" <<endl;
waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help and answers

Comment: #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)  ?  just a guess you want both for in parallel , I am wrong if not ~~~

Comment: You've programmed a data race.  Sure, that's a guess but to exclude the possibility you should explicitly declare the accessibility of all variables in each parallel region: `private`, `shared`, what-have-you.

Comment: There is a race condition in `gx`, `gy`, and `sum`.  They are all shared and should be made private.  Just define them when you use them inside the parallel loop and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a race condition in `gx`, `gy`, and `sum`. They are all shared and should be made private. Just define them when you use them inside the parallel loop and it should fix your problem.  Like this

```
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for(int y = 1; y < grey.rows - 1; y++){
        for(int x = 1; x < grey.cols - 1; x++){
            int gx = xGradient(grey, x, y);
            int gy = yGradient(grey, x, y);
            int sum = abs(gx) + abs(gy);
            sum = sum > 255 ? 255:sum;
            sum = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
            dst.at<uchar>(y,x) = sum;
```

Comment: Works fine, final image is clear now. But i have another problem: the time for openmp is longer than for single thread. For image 8000x5330 operation lasts 3,7859 sec without openmp and 5,746 with openmp (4 threads). Any idea how to improve speed?

Comment: I don't know.  It looks okay.  Maybe there is some false sharing but I don't see it right now.  You have only made the loop on rows parallel so no thread should ever write to the same row.  What is` dst.at<uchar>(y,x)`?  Is it the same as dst[width*y+x]?  If you format your text better you might get more responses.  Highlight the text and type ctrl-k then fix anything that's still not right.

Answer (score 0):

> i hope this can help u :)

```
 #pragma omp parallel for private (gx, gy, sum) //num_threads (2)
    for(int y = 1; y < grey.rows - 1; y++){
        for(int x = 1; x < grey.cols - 1; x++){     
            gx = xGradient(grey, x, y);
            gy = yGradient(grey, x, y);
            sum = abs(gx) + abs(gy);
            sum = sum > 255 ? 255:sum;
            sum = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
            dst.at<uchar>(y,x) = sum;
        }
    }
```